# How to detect and distinguish between first, second, and third increases in a vector of numbers

Tags: r, for-loop

Say I have the following vector:

```
vector <- c(5,5,11,11,7,16,16,16,12,8,20,24,20)
```

As we can see, there are 4 separate increases in this vector, though lets just say we only care about the first 3. These 3 increases are: from 2nd element to 3rd element (increase from 5 to 11, which is an increase of 6), from 5th element to 6th element (increase from 7 to 16, which is an increase of 9), and from 10th element to 11th element (increase from 8 to 20, which is an increase of 12). I am looking for some help on constructing some sort of for loop algorithm to store the amount of each of these increases in separate variables. Thus far, I know how to detect each of the increases, but I have no idea how to distinguish between each of them in order to store them separately. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `diff()` and subset the result to find the increases, take the first 3 using `head()` and convert to a list to separate.

```
dv <- diff(vector)
as.list(head(dv[dv > 0], 3))

[[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 9

[[3]]
[1] 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to compare each value in the vector to the value before it (using the `lag()` function from the [dplyr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html)) and only keep positive differences:

```r
library(dplyr)

vector <- c(5,5,11,11,7,16,16,16,12,8,20,24,20)

# differences between numbers
diffs <- vector - lag(vector)

# only keep the first three positive differences
head(diffs[which(diffs > 0)], 3)
#> [1]  6  9 12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>